# Understanding ' | ' and ' & ' operator behavior (logical operator of R)

Tags: r, logical-operators

If `F|F|F` returns FALSE and `F|T|F` or `T|F|F` returns TRUE, why are they returning different values?

```
F|F|F & F|F|F & F|T|F
F|F|F & F|F|F & T|F|F
```

Someone explain me why they return different values. My understanding says their value should be only FALSE.

Comment: Use `()` to separate the blocks

Comment: `&` has higher precedence to `|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we separate the blocks with `()`, would work as expected

```
(F|F|F) & (F|F|F )& (F|T|F)
 #[1] FALSE

(F|F|F) & (F|F|F) & (T|F|F) 
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Reason is operator precedence if we check the `?Syntax`